# iPhone app memory leak

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, memory-leaks

Any idea why this code gives me a memory leak? As you can see, I'm running out of ideas as to what I can do to stop it.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSArray *allSketches = [project.sketches allObjects];
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:allSketches];

    if(sketchesArray != nil) [sketchesArray release];

    [self setSketchesArray:temp];

    [allSketches release];
    allSketches = nil;
    [temp release];
    temp = nil;

}
```

I also release sketchesArray inside viewDidDissapear. I'm not using viewDidLoad and dealloc to init/release these objects as what I am doing requires me to use viewWillAppear and viewDidDissapear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using this instead:

```
NSArray *allSketches = [project.sketches allObjects];
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:allSketches];

[self setSketchesArray:temp];

[temp release];
```

Though I remember doing that and it didn't work before... Strange... There appear to still be some memory leaks coming from CoreGraphics though. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

Is this being released somewhere else when you are done with it?

```
[self setSketchesArray:temp];
```

Specifically, you are releasing sketchesArray in this function, but do you do that elsewhere when you are done with the view?

Comment: yes, it's released in dealloc. it works now, by the way. See above :)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the leak, but you've got a couple of probable over-releases.

The release of a non-`nil` `sketchesArray` should be managed inside `setSketchesArray`. And it doesn't look like you have local ownership of `allSketches` either...

Comment: you are right, thanks. I'm very new to this and still not used to the memory management system.